# two select statements in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008:

- `Customer` : `customerid, customername` (contains only one row)
- `Product` : `productid, productname, category, price` (contains multiple rows)

I want to get `customername` from `customer` table and `productname,category,price` from `product` table using 2 select statements in single stored procedure.

How to do it?

Comment: What did you try? Just google it.

Comment: Is there any relation between these table? If available why don't you go for join???

Comment: no relation. these are separate tables

Comment: I think you should add examples to show what do you want to do with these results. Do you want to return this or you need it to do some inner work in the SP? There are many ways to do it but you should make you aim clear.

Comment: A customer purchases some products. I want to get customer name with purchased products.

Comment: @AntonyPaulRaj: In this case you should use ORDERS table where the relation between Customers and Products is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Using temp table (#temp) concept you can do that. And the better one is to create relationship between that two table and write join queries.

Comment: u want one result set and u have two different select statement in ur SP. right ?